# Mysql sorted statement in average sale price

Tags: mysql, sql

Write one  (1) MySQL
query statement that returns the average sale price for properties that were ‘under contract’ in the
past month for each State where the agency operates. The result should be sorted from highest to
lowest by average sale price. Your query should return a table in the following format
i tried

```
select * from(
select   avg(sale_price)  from  purchase where property_id = 64
union all  (
select   avg(sale_price)  from  purchase where property_id = 60)
union (
select avg(sale_price) from purchase where property_id = 58))  as i
order by  sale_price  ASC;
```

i got this error as i have sale_price column in my table

> 22:08:19  select * from( select   avg(sale_price)  from  purchase where
> property_id = 64 union all  ( select   avg(sale_price)  from  purchase
> where property_id = 60) union ( select avg(sale_price) from purchase
> where property_id = 58))  as i order by  sale_price  ASC LIMIT 0,
> 1000  Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'sale_price' in 'order
> clause'   0.000 sec

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help you understand the problem -- as well as anyone else who wants to help.

Comment: Have you tried "order by i"?

Comment: As @RobMoll said, order by 1

Answer (score 1):

You should use an alias in the SELECT clause in every UNION.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    AVG(sale_price) AS sale_price 
  FROM
    purchase 
  WHERE property_id = 64 
  UNION
  ALL 
  (SELECT 
    AVG(sale_price)  AS sale_price 
  FROM
    purchase 
  WHERE property_id = 60) 
  UNION
  (SELECT 
    AVG(sale_price)  AS sale_price
  FROM
    purchase 
  WHERE property_id = 58)) AS i 
ORDER BY sale_price ASC ;
```

Or could you use the following query? I would think this is more straightforward on performance side.

```
SELECT 
  AVG(sale_price) AS avg_sale_price 
FROM
  purchase 
WHERE property_id IN (64, 60, 58) 
GROUP BY property_id 
ORDER BY avg_sale_price ;
```